Markov property in HJM model and Vasicek model
I am reading Section 5.1 The HJM Forward-Rate Dynamics in Brigo Mercurio.
Starting from the dynamics of the the instantaneous forward rate $f(t,T)$:
\begin{align}
df(t,T) = \alpha(t, T)dt + \sigma(t, T)dW(t),
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f(0,T) = f^M(0,T),
\end{align}
the authors derive the following expression for the instantaneous short rate $r(t)$:
\begin{align}
r(t) &= f(t,t) = f(0,t) + \int_0^t \sigma(u,t) \left( \int_u^t \sigma(u,s) ds \right) du + \int_0^t \sigma(s,t) dW(s) \\
&= f(0,t) + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_0^t \sigma_i(u,t) \left( \int_u^t \sigma_i(u,s) ds \right) du + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_0^t \sigma_i(s,t) dW_i(s).
\end{align}
They then explain that the short-rate process is not a Markov process in general. Notice the time $t$ appears in the stochastic integral both as extreme of integration and inside the integrand function. However, there are suitable specifications of $\sigma$ for which $r$ is indeed a Markov process. This happens, for example, if we can write, for each $i = 1, \ldots, N$,
\begin{align}
\sigma_i(t, T) = \xi_i(t) \psi_i(T),
\end{align}
with $\xi_i$ and $\psi_i$ strictly positive and deterministic functions of time. Under such a separable specification, the short-rate process becomes
\begin{align}
r(t) = f(0,t) + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_0^t \xi_i(u) \psi_i(t) \left( \int_u^t \xi_i(u) \psi_i(s) ds \right) du + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_0^t \xi_i(s) \psi_i(t) dW_i(s),
\end{align}
Questions:

Could you help me understand why the fact that $t$ appears in the stochastic integral both as extreme of integration and inside the integrand function makes the process for $r$ non-Markov? I understand the Markovian property, but I am confused about what is different in this case compared to the specification of $r$ in the Vasicek model:
\begin{align}
r(t) = r(s)e^{-k(t-s)} + \theta \left( 1 - e^{-k(t-s)} \right) + \sigma \int_s^t e^{-k(t-u)} dW(u).
\end{align}
Also in this case $t$ appears as extreme of integration and inside the integrand function.
What is peculiar about the specification $\sigma_i(t, T) = \xi_i(t) \psi_i(T)$ that makes the process for $r$ Markov?


1.The Vasicek model is Markovian because the stochastic differential equation of short rate r is only dependent on state t, dr(t) = k(θ-r(t))dt +σdW(t) 2. "Markov Representation of the Heath-Jarrow-Morton Model", Cheyette 1992 . I am not following exactly but it says with the separable specification we could derive Markovian state variables.
